# What user licenses contribute to File Storage limit(Used File Space) calculation in Unlimited edition which is currently 184%

Tags: file-storage, storage-limit

we have a org which is Unlimited edition and currently I can see Used File Space is 184%.

What I know at this stage is

Per User its assigned space is - 2GB

and we have following  user licenses.

Customer Community Plus -500

Chatter Free -5,000

Chatter External-500

Chatter Only

Salesforce -40

Identity - 10

Integration User - 1 So total licenses available are - 5,653 hence  5653   ×   2 = 11,306  GB So We have 11.36 TB and so far we used file space calculated is 219.5 GB (184%) [View]

Why is it showing as 184% how is this calculated?

Can get some thoughts and points to ponder please?
Screenshot of company Information
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not all licences count towards your file storage limits. The calculations according to [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_storage.htm&type=5) are as follows:

> File Storage Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise,
> Performance, and Unlimited Editions are allocated 10 GB of file
> storage per org. Essentials edition is allocated 1 GB of file storage
> per org.
>
> Orgs are allocated additional file storage based on the number of
> standard user licenses. In Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited
> Editions, orgs are allocated 2 GB of file storage per user license.
> Contact Manager, Group, Professional Edition orgs are allocated 612 MB
> per standard user license, which includes 100 MB per user license plus
> 512 MB per license for the Salesforce CRM Content feature license. An
> org with fewer than 10 users will receive a total of 1 GB of per-user
> file storage rather than 100 MB per user license.
>
> Each Salesforce CRM Content feature license provides an additional 512
> MB of file storage, whether Salesforce CRM Content is enabled or not.
>
> File storage and data storage are calculated asynchronously, so if you
> import or add a large number of records or files, the change in your
> org’s storage usage isn’t reflected immediately.
>
> The minimum values apply to Salesforce and Salesforce Platform user
> licenses. If your org uses custom user licenses, contact Salesforce to
> determine your exact storage amount.

Next to that your company can also buy extra storage.

If you have questions about this subject it may be easier to contact your Salesforce Account Manager.